# Drawing an ASCII grid in Ruby based on a 2D array

Tags: ruby, array, reinventing-the-wheel

I'm writing a function that renders a grid using ASCII line-drawing characters, based on a provided 2D array (or array of arrays), with each top-level array representing a row, and the items inside those arrays as columns.

The function works, but it is *absurdly* ugly and hard to read. I want to resolve that somehow, but the only things I can think of would already make a massive function even longer and more verbose.

How can this function be improved?

#### drawgrid

```
# Renders an ASCII grid based on a 2D array
def drawgrid(args, boxlen=3)
  #Define box drawing characters
  side = '│'
  topbot = '─'
  tl = '┌'
  tr = '┐'
  bl = '└'
  br = '┘'
  lc = '├'
  rc = '┤'
  tc = '┬'
  bc = '┴'
  crs = '┼'
  ##############################
  draw = []
  args.each_with_index do |row, rowindex|
    # TOP OF ROW Upper borders
    row.each_with_index do |col, colindex|
      if rowindex == 0
        colindex == 0 ? start = tl : start = tc
        draw << start + (topbot*boxlen)
        colindex == row.length - 1 ? draw << tr : ""
      end
    end
    draw << "\n" if rowindex == 0

    # MIDDLE OF ROW: DATA
    row.each do |col|
      draw << side + col.to_s.center(boxlen)
    end
    draw << side + "\n"

    # END OF ROW
    row.each_with_index do |col, colindex|
      if colindex == 0
        rowindex == args.length - 1 ? draw << bl : draw << lc
        draw << (topbot*boxlen)
      else
        rowindex == args.length - 1 ? draw << bc : draw << crs
        draw << (topbot*boxlen)
      end
      endchar = rowindex == args.length - 1 ? br : rc

      #Overhang elimination if the next row is shorter
      if args[rowindex+1]
        if args[rowindex+1].length < args[rowindex].length
          endchar = br
        end
      end
      colindex == row.length - 1 ? draw << endchar : ""
    end
    draw << "\n"
  end


  draw.each do |char|
    print char
  end
  return true
end
```

#### Usage

```
drawgrid([[123,456,789,'baz'], ['abc','def','ghi'], ['foo', 'bar'], ['buz']])

# Output
┌───┬───┬───┬───┐
│123│456│789│baz│
├───┼───┼───┼───┘
│abc│def│ghi│
├───┼───┼───┘
│foo│bar│
├───┼───┘
│buz│
└───┘
```

It is a known limitation with the code given that grids with more columns in later rows will display incorrectly. For the purpose this function is being used for, it is an acceptable limitation. I'm okay with fixing it as long as it doesn't bloat this method even further.

I'm also aware of a ruby library, `terminal-table`, but it's not 100% suited for the kind of terse output I'm looking for. This will be used to display an IP space map, while `terminal-table` appears to work better for formatted tables like MySQL output.

Comment: How flexible does this need to be, in terms of different numbers of rows/columns being specified?

Comment: Well, there are only 45 valid subnet masks,so there's a hard limit on how many combinations there could possibly be. And I also really only want a maximum of 16 grid squares per row. (80 column terminal, with five characters per cell including borders)